# How to apply multiple NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot at once?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource, nsdiffabledatasourcesnapshot

I'm building `UICollectionView` with new diffable `NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot` and `NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot`. I need to use `NS…SectionSnapshot` to populate my `UICollectionView` with outline items.

First, I create `NS…Snapshot`, set all section and root items and apply this snapshot, then for each section that contains outline items I create `NS…SectionSnapshot`, set all items here and apply these snapshots.

Pseudocode:

```swift
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Section, Item>()
snapshot.appendSection(sections)
snapshot.appendItems(items1, toSection: section1)
snapshot.appendItems(items2, toSection: section2)
dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
…

var sectionSnapshot1 = NSDiffableDataSourceSectionSnapshot<Item>()
sectionSnapshot1.append([rootItem1])
sectionSnapshot1.append(outlineItems1, to: rootItem1)
…

dataSource.apply(sectionSnapshot1, to: section1, animatingDifferences: false)
…
```

This first step works correct.

But then I receive the new data from the server, parse and store it to my view model and trigger new update — I receive the crash.

Pseudocode for update:

```swift
// This part completely identical to the very first setup of dataSource (see above)
// Note, that at this point some cells may be deleted or inserted by dataSource because I change the snapshot. 
// (For example, I have 3 values and I construct the specific row for them; if there are no values I show one-line text "No data".)

// Here I just reconfigure some existing items
var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
snapshot.reconfigureItems(items)
dataSource.applySnapshot(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
```

First error I received is on line (when I try to apply "root items" snapshot):

> dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)

Error message:

> *** Assertion failure in -[_UITreeDataSourceSnapshotter childrenForParentAtIndex:recursive:], _UITreeDataSourceSnapshotter.mm:256
>
> Thread 1: "Invalid parameter not satisfying: globalIndex < self.count"

Well, I think it's trying to say that "You're applying snapshot without outline items, so there is some problem". But why? I disable the animation and the next line is all about applying these outline items…

The next thing I did is to remove this line (applying "root items" snapshot) and try to only apply the sections I need. But, when I apply the first section it also triggers the update of some other cells in other section. The problem is that at this point I don't have my previous data and I receive the crash. Again, why?

As I understand my main problem is how to apply all snapshots at once to prevent all this errors? OR there is other right way to manage this kind of layout that I should use?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this issue? I'm facing the same error but with different steps to reproduce.

Comment: Hi @SilisAlin, unfortunately no.